# AppDomain + Named pipe serialization performance

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following situation: An order is scanned under a barcode scanner, the ordernumber gets sent to a windows service application which will compute and send back the price. It takes discount coupons into account among other things and the discount are handled in a separate assembly.
What I wanted to do is to be able to unload the assembly at runtime so the dll can be replaced without having to stop the service. (the service takes 30 minutes to start up)
So I came up with the idea to create a new AppDomain that will load the assembly and execute code in there. Communication is done through named pipes and serialization.
Functionally it runs fine but in production performance gets really low. Does anybody have any advice on how to make the code below run as fast possible?

Explanation of the code: 
For every order with discount DoAction is called. It first fires up a thread which acts as named pipe client. That thread receives the price which is sent back to the client.
Then a new AppDomain is loaded if it hasnt already and AppDomainCallback is executed in the context of that AppDomain. A named pipe server is started there and the assembly containing the discount code is loaded and called when the client connects and the results are deserialized back into the client thread and returned from DoAction. So theres a lot of thread waiting and serializing going on but I dont see a way to make it faster.

```
[Serializable]
internal class ActionLoader
{
    private const string DOMAINNAME = "Actions";

    private const string PIPE_TO = "PipeTo";
    private const string PIPE_BACK = "PipeBack";

    private string assemblyName;
    private string className;
    private string methodName;
    private List<object> parameters;

    private static BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    public ActionLoader(string assemblyName, string className, string methodName, List<object> parameters)
    {
        this.assemblyName = assemblyName;
        this.className = className;
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    private static AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(DOMAINNAME);

    public OrderPrice DoAction()
    {
        // after clientThread is done it fills RetVal
        ThreadedExecuter<OrderPrice> clientThread = new ThreadedExecuter<OrderPrice>(NamedPipeClient, parameters);
        clientThread.Start();

        if (domain == null) // domain can be unloaded by ropsrefresh so check if it should be created again
        {
            domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(DOMAINNAME);
        }
        // AppDomainCallback runs in the context of appdomain so dll's get loaded in there and not in CurrentDomain
        domain.DoCallBack(AppDomainCallback);

        clientThread.Thread.Join();

        return clientThread.RetVal; // return price deseralized from AppDomain
    }

    public static void UnloadAppDomain() // called by ropsrefresh => refresh config
    {
        if (domain != null)
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(domain);
            domain = null;
        }
    }

    private void AppDomainCallback()
    {
        OrderPrice price = null;

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);

        object action = assembly.CreateInstance(className);
        MethodInfo mi = action.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

        // using pipes to communicate between AppDomains
        using (NamedPipeServerStream stream = new NamedPipeServerStream(PIPE_TO))
        {
            stream.WaitForConnection();

            List<object> parameters = (List<object>)DeserializeFromStream(stream);

            Type t = action.GetType();

            if (mi != null)
                price = (OrderPrice)mi.Invoke(action, parameters.ToArray());
        }

        // server becomes client to serialize data back
        using (NamedPipeClientStream stream = new NamedPipeClientStream(PIPE_BACK))
        {
            stream.Connect();
            SerializeToStream(stream, price);
        }
    }

    private static OrderPrice NamedPipeClient(object parameters)
    {
        OrderPrice price = null;

        // using pipes to communicate between AppDomains
        using (NamedPipeClientStream stream = new NamedPipeClientStream(PIPE_TO))
        {
            stream.Connect();
            SerializeToStream(stream, parameters); // serialize function parameters to pipe stream
        }

        using (NamedPipeServerStream stream = new NamedPipeServerStream(PIPE_BACK))
        {
            stream.WaitForConnection();

            price = (OrderPrice)DeserializeFromStream(stream);
        }

        return price; // returns deserialized price to ThreadedExecutor
    }

    private static object DeserializeFromStream(Stream stream)
    {
        return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }

    private static void SerializeToStream(Stream stream, object parameters)
    {            
        formatter.Serialize(stream, parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrote the code to use the Task library. This performs better since it uses the windows ThreadPool. task.Result will block until the task is done so no join needed anymore.

```
public OrderPrice DoAction()
{
    Task<OrderPrice> task = Task<OrderPrice>.Factory.StartNew(NamedPipeClient);

    if (domain == null)
        domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(DOMAINNAME);
    domain.DoCallBack(AppDomainCallback);

    return task.Result; 
}
```